# intersection of ordinals

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $\alpha,\beta$ be ordinal numbers and define $\gamma=\alpha \cap \beta$. I have already proven that it is an ordinal number itself but I must now prove that either $\gamma = \alpha$ or $\gamma = \beta$, and subsequently that either $\alpha \in \beta$, $\alpha = \beta$ or $\beta \in \alpha$. I wanted to try induction but I was unable to prove that they have the same minimum. At this point I only have de definition of a ordinal number i.e. a transitive set that is well ordered by $\in$, the recursion principle and the induction principle.  Could anyone help me?

Comment: What tools are already available if you don not have trichotomy yet?

Comment: These are fairly basic properties of ordinals, so what you must be doing with the exercise is part of actually _developing_ the standard properties of ordinals. That makes it important which standard properties you _already_ have available. Do you know, for example, that if $\alpha,\beta$ are ordinals and $\alpha\subseteq \beta$ then either $\alpha=\beta$ or $\alpha\in\beta$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that $\alpha, \beta$ are transitive and are well-ordered by $\in$.
Let $\gamma=\alpha\cap \beta$. Then $\gamma$ is transitive: If $x\in y\in\gamma$, then also $x\in y \in\alpha$ by transitivity of $\alpha$, hence $x\in\alpha$; similarly $x\in\beta$, henec $x\in\gamma$.
Assume $\alpha\setminus \gamma$ is nonempty and let $\gamma_1=\min(\alpha\setminus \gamma)$.
Let $x\in\gamma_1$. Then $x\in\alpha$ and by minimality of $\gamma_1$, $x\in\gamma$, so that $\gamma_1\subseteq \gamma$. On the other hand, we have $\gamma_1\notin\gamma$ because $\gamma_1\in\alpha\setminus\gamma$; hence if $x\in \gamma$, then certainly $x\ne\gamma_1$; but also $\gamma_1\notin x$ as otherwise again $\gamma_1\in\gamma$ by transitivity of $\gamma$. Therefore $x\in\gamma_1$ holds. So we find that also $\gamma\subseteq \gamma_1$, i.e. $\gamma_1=\gamma$. LSimilarly, if $\beta\setminus \gamma$ is nonempty we conclude that $\min(\beta\setminus \gamma)=\gamma$. But then $\gamma\in\alpha\cap\beta$ so that we have (e.g. in $\alpha$) the relation $\gamma\in\gamma$, contradicting the well (or even total) ordering of $\alpha$. Therefore at least one of the sets $\alpha\setminus \gamma$, $\beta\setminus\gamma$ must be empty.

Comment: how does the minimality of $\gamma_1$ imply that $x\in \gamma$? Didn't you construct $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma$ to be disjoint?

Comment: @hausdorff Any element of $\alpha$ that is $<$ (i.e. $\in$) the *minimal* element of $\alpha\setminus\gamma$ cannot be in $\alpha\setminus\gamma$.